# update query with xml sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having problem in updating database from xml and dynamic query.

```
Exec('UPDATE ' + @DbInstance + 'dbo.tblAcademic
      SET tblacademic.RollNo = XMLAcademic.Item.value(''@RollNo'', ''VARCHAR(50)''), 
          tblacademic.Board = XMLAcademic.Item.value(''@Board'', ''VARCHAR(150)''),
          tblacademic.PassingYear = XMLAcademic.Item.value(''@PassingYear'', ''VARCHAR(10)''),
          tblacademic.Semester = XMLAcademic.Item.value(''@Semester'', ''VARCHAR(5)''),
          tblacademic.MarksObt = XMLAcademic.Item.value(''@MarksObt'', ''varchar(9)''),
          tblacademic.MaxMarks = XMLAcademic.Item.value(''@MaxMarks'', ''int'') 
      FROM ''' + Convert(varchar, @XMLEducationalDetail) + '''.nodes(''/root/row'') AS XMLAcademic(Item) 
      WHERE tblacademic.AcademicID = XMLAcademic.Item.value(''@AcademicID'', ''int'')')
```

This is showing error at Convert function and without convert function there is also execution error showing xml to nvarchar error.

Comment: Does the query work when you execute it directly, without the dynamic SQL overhead? Also: if you convert to `varchar`, I would recommend to always define a length! Use: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), ......) ` or something that suits your needs

Comment: @marc_s: it is working directly. yes not showing any error.

Comment: @marc_s: what's wrong with dynamic query??

Comment: Doesn't `CONVERT(VARCHAR,...)` implicitly convert to `VARCHAR(30)`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx You may be truncating data. Also I assume `@DbInstance` has a `.` at the end of it, or is always empty.

Comment: You should print the query string you build so you can se what you actually try to do. It looks to me like you try to call the .nodes function on a string. You need to cast the string to XML in a subquery and then you can use the result in a cross apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "advanced" expressions in EXEC(...) statements, only constants, variables and string concatenations, so convert doesn't work there.

Create a separate variable and put the converted value there. Also, as someone else mention, you should use CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @XMLEducationalDetail) and not just VARCHAR